# OTA Update Error - "Package expects build fingerprint of ..."

Tags: rooting, ota-update, system-error

I unrooted and re-installed stock recovery from CWM on my Nvidia Shield Tablet. But when I tried to install an OTA, I got However when I tried to install the update, I got a red triangle error. After checking the log I got an error saying "Package expects build fingerprint of ... or ..., this device has ...."

I can't remember what the fingerprints were, but the first one was something that began with "nvidia/", had a bunch of numbers in the middle followed by an underscore, then it ended with "/release-keys".

However the device's current build fingerprint was exactly the same as the first, ***except that it cut off halfway through***, right after the numbers and the underscore.

Resetting the cache didn't work. How was this error caused, and how can I fix this without wiping my data?

Comment: As far as I know. You cant install an OTA with a custom recovery. Not unless you download the OTA and manually flash it. I had a similar problem when I was trying to be lazy when going back to stock for the recall. Ended up downloading the stock image and flashing with adb/fastboot. Did you download the stock image from nvidia's website? Also not sure why it would be asking for finerprints seeing how the device doesnt have a f.print scanner.

Comment: @jer3my it's "build fingerprint", an identifier of a build (e.g. firmware), not a physical fingerprint.

Comment: @AndrewT. oh derp. My bad. Lol

Comment: Anyone having the same issue? I have given an explanation [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144737/96277). Read from: *No, you cannot switch to any random newer update using incremental OTA update...*

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue when trying to update OTA from Android 4.4.4 to Android 5.1 and now from Android 5.1 to a new version.

I'm assuming your phone is rooted and you have a custom recovery installed.

## 1. Find out your build fingerprint.

- Install [CID Getter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tritonsoft.cidgetter&hl=en) and check the `ro.build.fingerprint` entry.

  > (In my case, its value is `motorola/peregrine_retbr/peregrine:5.1/LPB23.13-35.5/5:user/release-keys`)

### Check your value again.

### Double-check it, and triple-check it, it's **very, very, VERY** important to get it right to the last bit.

## 2. Obtain the zip file for your OTA update

Start the OTA update process (settings -> phone -> check updates). It will download a file and place it on your internal memory, for instance for me it's `/cache/Blur<long file name>.zip`.

Obtain that file and place it on your computer (I have used my custom TeamWin recovery to do that).

## 3. Check the updater script

Inside this zip file, there will be a file called `/META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script`.

There will be a line similar to the one below:

```
getprop("ro.build.fingerprint") == "motorola/peregrine_retbr/peregrine:5.1/LPB23.13-35.5/5:user/release-keys" || 
getprop("ro.build.fingerprint") == "motorola/peregrine_retbr/peregrine:5.1/LPBS23.13-35.5-1/1:user/release-keys" ||
abort("Package expects build fingerprint of motorola/peregrine_retbr/peregrine:5.1/LPB23.13-35.5/5:user/release-keys or motorola/peregrine_retbr/peregrine:5.1/LPBS23.13-35.5-1/1:user/release-keys; this device has " + getprop("ro.build.fingerprint") + ".");
```

What's it doing in this case? This line checks for the build fingerprint and aborts the process if it's not *exactly* either `motorola/peregrine_retbr/peregrine:5.1/LPB23.13-35.5/5:user/release-keys` or `motorola/peregrine_retbr/peregrine:5.1/LPBS23.13-35.5-1/1:user/release-keys`.

## 4. Compare your build and the updater script.

Seriously. Check it again.

## 5. Edit the updater script

Delete this line. Place the edited file on the zip file.

## 6. Patch and be happy!

Use your custom recovery to apply the patch without signature verification.

### OBS:

If you have flashed anything that modifies system files -- including, but not limited to, SuperSU and the Xposed framework -- you might need to revert those files to their original state, since the OTA update will perform a check on many system files. In order to revert those files, consult the documentation from whatever you flashed.

Comment: Did this worked with anyone I have same error?

Comment: @TechWolf It didn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't immediately applicable to OP's Nvidia tablet, but I'll leave it here in case it's useful to others.

https://mirrors.lolinet.com/ hosts many Motorola stock ROMs. I don't know if the site is trustworthy or not, but I'm using it now.

After you download a stock zip, use https://github.com/dlenski/motoflash2sh to generate a flashing shell script which doesn't depend on the existence of an existing unmodified stock ROM. The resulting script will have `fastboot erase userdata || exit 1`. Remove or comment-out this line if you don't want to clear all data on the phone.

I don't know if you can install those zip files through TWRP.